# Removing common letter from a string iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, nsstring, distinct

I have a string **Mumbai-London-London** I want to check if the string contains any repeated content. In this case London is repeated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example I assume that everything is hyphen separated, so, you can use `componentsSeparatedByString:` to split into an array of words. Then, depending on whether you want to maintain order or not you can create a set from the array to remove the duplicates or you can iterate over the array and add each item to a new array if the destination array doesn't already contain the string. Then you can use `componentsJoinedByString:` to get back to a string again.